# Will Insure++ detect array overflows in a C structure on the heap?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I have been trying to find the best programs to detect buffer overflows in a C program. In particular I am looking to detect overflows of a char array that exists within a C structure on the heap.

For example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
    struct mystruct
    {
        char fill[4];
        char g[4];
        char h[4];
    };

    /* A structure on the heap */
    struct mystruct *strheap =
       (struct mystruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));

    memset(strheap, 0, sizeof(struct mystruct));

    printf("Before overrun array but not structure\n");
    sprintf(strheap->fill, "12345678901");

    printf("Before overrun array and structure but only by 1 byte\n");
    sprintf(strheap->g, "12345678");

    printf("Before free\n");
    free(strheap);
    printf("Before return\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Would Insure++ be able to detect the two array overflows in this test program?

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself and tell us as well?

Comment: Off Topic: sprintf and its cousins are bad in general. You might want to consider grepping for it and replacing it with something more sane, like: http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf

Comment: @ArjunShankar: For what he's doing, something from the `strcpy` family, like `strncpy`, would be better.

Comment: @BenVoigt - You are right. But I was referring purely to the unsafe nature of functions like sprintf and its cousins (where I would also throw in strcpy).

Comment: @Als I have tried a couple so far and I am trying to save some time (actually lots of time). I figured if anyone has Insure++ it would be relatively easy to try the test sample program or possibly know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From experience, yes.  Provided you're actually overflowing the array (one or two elements past the end), and not wildly dereferencing waaaaay past the end.</strike>

Oh wait, I misunderstood the question, thought you were asking about arrays of structures.

In your case, I think it will detect if you access an out-of-bounds index, but an overflowing into the next member inside a library function will not be detected (the extra instrumentation on indexing will not occur).  Only if the library function writes beyond the object (the entire structure, or maybe even a structure/array containing the structure) can library function buffer overflow be detected.

For one thing, it's perfectly legal and reasonable to

```
sizeof mystruct one, two;
memcpy(&one, &two, sizeof (struct mystruct));
```

which copies over all four arrays.  Insure++ isn't going to flag that.

And in fact, the `memset` in your question does the same thing.

Comment: Your example of memcpy'ing a struct is quite the same thing. If you specify the structure you are saying you want to copy the structure. If you specify a structure element you are saying you want to work on that element so I would think that catching this would be useful. When you said it will catch an out of bounds index, do you mean a literal index (array[5]) or will it also work on an index set at runtime (array[index])?

Comment: @user265445: `memcpy` receives an address, devoid of any type information.  And I meant a variable index.  Insure++ inserts index-checking logic wherever you use the array subscript operator `[]`, if it can determine the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool will find accesses outside of struct *members* regardless of where the struct exists.  In particular, it will also find errors in access in variables that are stack allocated or thread allocated (valgrind will not do this).

In your example, *your* code doesn't directly commit an access error; you've pushed (hidden) the problem in the sprintf call.   CheckPointer will find this, too. It uses a library of replacements for standard library calls that include such checking.   It won't detect bad accesses with operations such as memset or memcpy.

You can download a version that should be able to do your example directly.

[CheckPointer is available for C, but not yet for C++.]

Answer (score 0):

I am currently evaluating insure, so i could test your program.
The log below is generated at runtime after compiling and linking main.c with insure:

```
[main.c] (Thread 0) **WRITE_OVERFLOW**
>> #include "stdio.h"

  Writing overflows memory: strheap->g

          bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
          |     4     |          8           | 1 |
                      wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

   Writing  (w) : 0x3002247c thru 0x30022484 (9 bytes)
   To block (b) : 0x30022478 thru 0x30022483 (12 bytes)
                 strheap, allocated in main.c
                          malloc()  (interface)
                            main()  main.c

  Stack trace where the error occurred:
                            main()  main.c

**Memory corrupted.  Program may crash!!**

[main.c] (Thread 0) **HEAP_CORRUPT**
>> #include "stdio.h"

  The heap is corrupt.

          bbbbbb
          | 12 | 16  |
               xgggggg

  Guardzone      : 0x30022484 thru 0x30022493 (16 bytes)
  Expected   (g) : fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  Found      (x) : 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
                   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

  Near Block (b) : 0x30022478 thru 0x30022483 (12 bytes)
                  strheap, allocated in main.c
                          malloc()  (interface)
                            main()  main.c

stack trace where memory was freed:
                            free()  (interface)
                            main()  main.c

  Stack trace where error was detected:
                            free()  (interface)
                            main()  main.c

** TCA log data will be merged with tca.log **
************************* INSURE SUMMARY ************************ v7.4.3 **
*   Program      : a.out                                                  *
*   Arguments    :                                                        *
*   Directory    : ~/test/stackoverflow                  *
*   Compiled on  : Jun 13, 2013  07:59:47                                 *
*   Run on       : Jun 13, 2013  07:59:54                                 *
*   Elapsed time : 00:00:00                                               *
*   Malloc HWM   : 48649 bytes (47K)                                      *
***************************************************************************

PROBLEM SUMMARY - by type
===============

          Problem                Reported      Suppressed
          -------------------------------------------------
          HEAP_CORRUPT                 1                0
          WRITE_OVERFLOW               1                0
          -------------------------------------------------
          TOTAL                        2                0
          -------------------------------------------------

PROBLEM SUMMARY - by location
===============

HEAP_CORRUPT: The heap is corrupt, 1 unique occurrence
         1 in main.c

WRITE_OVERFLOW: Writing overflows memory, 1 unique occurrence
         1 in main.c
```

Comment: So it detects writing beyond the end of the struct (e.g., the OP's write to "strheap->g", but not beyond the end of the struct member ("strheap->fill").  CheckPointer will detect the write beyond the end of the struct member.